# CodeIgniter switching between many accounts

Tags: codeigniter, session, switch-statement, codeigniter-2, user-accounts

I'm developing an application, where in a user can be a `doctor` or `patient`. The table structure as follows.

```
users(id, first, last, email, phone);
doctors(id, name, phone, user_id);
patients(id, name, phone, user_id);
Each user can have many doctors and patients.
```

Following are the purposes played by a user.

1. User is only for authentication.
2. If user as a patient, he can do appointments.
3. If user as a doctor, he can approve the appointments.

If the user selects `doctor accounts`, he can literally works as `doctor` throughout the application and same applies to `patient` also. This can be implemented by using `session`. But I don't know how to come up with a solution. Please help me out. The work would be more appreciated.

Comment: why are `doctors` and `patients` the same columns but different database tables? Normalize your data!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the user role in session.

> $this->session->set_userdata(array("user_role"=>"P/D")); //p = patient
>   , D - doctor. whatever method you used.

Then you can check role before every action to allow user to do.

> if($this->session->userdata("user_role") == "P")
>
> {
>
> //return as patient
>
> }